# Stopping JavaScript Promises from Propagating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

Imagine I have a promise chain like the one below. If func2 is called, I would like to avoid func3 or func4 from being called altogether.

```
AsyncFunction()
.then(func1, func2)
.then(func3, func4)
```

At the moment, If I throw an error in func2, func4 would be called. If I return a value in func2, func3 seems to be called.

I am using Angular $q.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use nesting for branching control flow. In your case, it would look like this:

```
AsyncFunction().then(function(res) {
    return func1(res).then(func3, func4);
}, func2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if there's a way to resolve this without nesting? It looks like this could get quite messy in some scenarios.

Comment: No. In structured programming, you always will use nesting for something like branching - consider a simple `if` statement. If things get too complex, move them to their own function.