# Promise control flow - catch versus onRejected

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I am currently wondering why the throw in this ES6 native Promise setup is not arriving in the catch block

```
new Promise(function(resolve,reject){

    reject('bar')

}).then(function resolved(){

    console.log('resolved 1');

}, function rejected(){

    console.log('rejected 1')
    throw new Error();

}).then(function resolved(val){

    console.log('resolved 2');

}, function rejected(){

    console.log('rejected 2');

}).catch(function(err){

    console.log('catch');

});
```

I am looking for a way to get the control flow to the catch block, but if I use a rejected handler, if I throw an error, the control ends up there, and not in the catch.

In simpler terms, I am looking for a way to end up in the catch block, even if there is a onRejected handler...is there a way to do that?

```
new Promise(function(resolve,reject){

    throw new Error(); // this goes to onRejected
    reject('bar'); // this goes to onRejected


}).then(function onResolved(){

    console.log('resolved');

}, function onRejected(){

    console.log('rejected')


}).catch(function(err){

    console.log('catch');

});
```

my goal is to branch separately, based on whether an error is thrown versus whether reject is called. Not sure if it's possible. Perhaps there is a way to call catch explicitly? *I'd like to find a way to do this without explicitly throwing a new error in the final onRejected handler* if possible.

Here is my goal, with comments:

```
new Promise(function(resolve,reject){

    if(success){
       resolve('success');   //this goes to next onResolved
    }
    else if(fail){
       reject('fail');      //this goes to next onRejected (or catch if there is no onRejected)
    }
    else {
       throw new Error('Fatal');  //this goes to next catch
    }

});
```

that's the behavior I am looking for

Comment: When you "handle" the rejection with a reject handler, the reject is considered "handled" now and the promise state changes to fulfilled unless you either return a rejected promise from the reject handler or you throw from the reject handler.  That's the way promise reject handlers are designed.  You cannot change that.  Throw or return a rejected promise if you want the rejection to NOT be handled and to continue to propagate.  There is no way around that fundamental design decision.

Comment: You cannot distinguish between "next catch" and "next onrejected" - `.catch(…)` is just sugar for `.then(null, …)` and behaves exactly the same. If you want to branch, you should [actually branch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27218802/1048572).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the error is not arriving at `.catch()` is due to error being handled within `onRejected`.

To pass error handled within `onRejected` to chained `.catch()` `throw` error again within `onRejected`

```js
new Promise(function(resolve,reject){

    throw new Error(); // this goes to onRejected
    reject('bar'); // this goes to onRejected


}).then(function onResolved(){

    console.log('resolved');

}, function onRejected(err){

    console.log('rejected')
    throw err

}).catch(function(err){

    console.log(err, 'catch');

});
```

---

Edit, Updated

To handle error before `onRejected` add `.catch()` before chained `.then()`

```js
var success = 0,
  fail;

var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  if (success) {
    resolve('success'); //this goes to next onResolved
  } else if (fail) {
    reject('fail'); //this goes to next onRejected (or catch if there is no onRejected)
  } else {
    throw new Error('Fatal'); //this goes to next catch
  }

});

p.catch(function(err) {
    console.log("error handled within catch:", err)
})
.then(function(data) {
    // error handled, `p` is now `resolved`
    console.log("resolved", data)
  }, function(err) {
    console.log("rejected", err)
})
```

Comment: yeah, thanks, but actually, I want to avoid that as it stands, because this is for a library and I don't want to require that users throw in onRejected, I want to have some flow go directly to the catch...does that make sense?

Comment: _"I want to have some flow go directly to the catch"_ Not certain interpret this correctly ?

Comment: perhaps I can throw in on resolved, instead of on rejected...that would be a trick

Comment: basically, I want to branch code -->  if the flow ends up in the catch, it means one thing (a more fatal error) then if the flow ends up in on rejected (less fatal error)..that's my current goal

Comment: Yes, could use `throw` within `onResolved`. Though, if error is handled in an `onRejected`  before `.catch()` , error would not reach subsequent  `.catch()`

Comment: What is the purpose of including both `onRejected` and `.catch()` ? Why can error not be handled in `onRejected` ?

Comment: simply because it simplifies the behavior of the library

Comment: What is logic on how to distinguish different errors ; what is difference between a _"more fatal error"_  and a _"less fatal error"_? Tried using an `if..else` statement within either `onRejected` or `.catch()` to handle errors differently ?

Comment: I could have the users of my library use a switch statement to distinguish between errors. But there is a difference between a soft error (a reject) and a hard/fatal error that means there is an unexpected error, which I believe belongs in the catch block

Comment: I added one more block of code in the question to illustrate

Comment: @AlexMills See updated post

Comment: ahhh, that should work, the catch before the next then, good one, let me test it

Comment: fml, if we put the catch before the then, what happens is that onResolved gets called, how to prevent onResolved from being called after the catch? I want to branch the logic

Comment: _"how to prevent onResolved from being called after the catch?"_ `throw` error , as described at initial stacksnippets

Comment: yes, but then the error will get swallowed, because I don't want another catch after the then...

Comment: _"how to prevent onResolved from being called after the catch?"_ What is expected result ? The error was handled , the `Promise` returned from `.catch()` now has a resolved status

Comment: http://openmymind.net/Cancelling-Long-Promise-Chains/

Comment: Not certain what link is attempting to describe ?

Comment: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/03/cancelable-async-operations-promises-javascript/

Comment: the bottom line is that I want to branch using promises, but I can't branch, it always goes to the next handler, no matter what

Comment: Again, what is expected result once error is handled ? For both `.then()` or `.catch()` that are possibly chained to do nothing ?

Comment: let me describe my use case - I have a rate limiting library, using redis. either the request exceeds the rate limit or it doesn't exceed the rate limit, or some error is thrown (redis error etc)...I want resolve to represent an OK request, I want reject to represent a request that exceeds the limit, and I want catch to represent an error that gets thrown inside my lib

Comment: Are you attempting to re-define `.catch()` ? `Promise` does not process in that manner; although you could try using `unhandledrejection` or `rejectionandled` events in chrome / chromium 49+ ; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35398365/js-promises-fulfill-vs-resolve/

Comment: yeah, it's quite possible that native ES6 promises can't do what I want

Comment: The simplest approach would be to use `if..else` statement in either `.catch()` or `onRejected` and `throw` if error should be passed

Comment: yeah, I think you're right

Comment: @AlexMills See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042068/why-is-onrejected-not-called-following-promise-all-where-promise-reject-incl